# send email notification to sales representative once order is confirmed failed

Tags: php, woocommerce, orders, http-error, tax

I have written below code to send the notification once the order status changed is completed. but I don't know why the code is not working. Whenever I tried to change the order status its redirected to a blank page with 500 error code. and Can you tell me how to get tax details in the below code.

> ***send email notification to sales representative once order is
>   confirmed***

```
 add_action("woocommerce_order_status_changed",
 "my_awesome_publication_notification", 10, 3 );

function my_awesome_publication_notification($order_id, $checkout=null) {

    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );

    $order_total_amount = $order->get_formatted_order_total();  

    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
         $product_name= $item['name'];
        $product_id= $item['product_id'];

    }

    $_product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
    $product_regular_price = $_product->get_regular_price();

    $order_data = $order->get_data();
    $order_date_created = $order_data['date_created'];  
    $order_o_total = $order_data['total'];
    $order_discount_total = $order_data['discount_total'];
    $order_total_tax1 = $order_data['total_tax'];

    if($order->status === 'completed' ) {

        if( $order->get_used_coupons() ) {

            foreach( $order->get_used_coupons() as $coupon) {

                $coupon_name = $coupon;
                /* get coupon's details */
                $coupon_post_obj = get_page_by_title($coupon, OBJECT, 'shop_coupon');
                $coupon_id = $coupon_post_obj->ID;

                $coupons_obj = new WC_Coupon($coupon_id); /* get coupon instance */

                $coupon_discount_amount = $coupons_obj->get_discount_amount();  
                $sales_representative_name          = get_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'sales_representative_name', true );
                $sales_representative_email_address = get_post_meta( $coupon_id, 'sales_representative_email_address', true );
            }

            $to = $sales_representative_email_address;
            $subject = 'New Order Completed Using Assigned Coupon Code';

            $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
            $headers .= 'From: My Name <nanganstella@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";

            $message = '<html><body>';  
            $message .= '<h1>A new order has been completed using assigned coupon code.<br/></h1>';

            $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';

            $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Product</strong></td><td>'. $product_name .'</td></tr>';

            $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Coupons used</strong></td><td>'. $coupon_name .'</td></tr>';

            $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Date</strong></td><td>'. $order_date_created .'</td></tr>';

            $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Product Price</strong></td><td>'. $product_regular_price .'CFA</td></tr>';

            $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Order Discount </strong></td><td>'. $order_discount_total.'CFA</td></tr>';

            $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Order Tax </strong></td><td>'. $order_total_tax1 .'</td></tr>';

            $message .= '<tr><td><strong>Order Amount</strong></td><td>'. $order_total_amount .'</td></tr>';                

            $message .= '</table>'; 
            $message .= '</body></html>';

            wp_mail( $to, $subject, $message, $headers );

        }
    }

}
```

**error: status was called incorrectly. Order properties should not be accessed directly.**

```
Backtrace: require('wp-blog-header.php'), 
require_once('wp-includes/template-loader.php'),
do_action('template_redirect'), 
WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, 
WC_AJAX::do_wc_ajax, 
do_action('wc_ajax_checkout'), 
WP_Hook->do_action, 
WP_Hook->apply_filters, 
WC_AJAX::checkout, 
WC_Checkout->process_checkout, 
WC_Checkout->process_order_payment, 
WC_Gateway_BACS->process_payment, 
WC_Order->update_status, 
WC_Order->save, 
WC_Order->status_transition, 
do_action('woocommerce_order_status_changed'), 
WP_Hook->do_action, 
WP_Hook->apply_filters, 
my_awesome_publication_notification, 
WC_Abstract_Legacy_Order->__get, 
wc_doing_it_wrong. This message was added in version 3.0.
```

Comment: When an error 500 is returned to your browser, there should be something printed to your server's error log. Search for that message and attach it to your question